# PDO query not returning records (sometimes)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently we are checking a PHP script which was designed severall years ago by someone else (external).

The script is using PDO and now I have the following problem.

Database layout **Loper** Table

```
id    korte_tekst    lengte    type    kg    field1    price    price_inc
79    766            500       TYPE1   60    Ja        40.70    49.11
80    760            270       TYPE_2  40    Ja        23.97    23.97
```

When I run below script / SQL

```
$sql = 'SELECT price FROM loper WHERE id = 80';
$loper = $this->db->query($sql);

foreach($loper as $lop)
{
    echo 'Price' . $lop['price'];       
}
```

I don't get any results back, but when running

```
$sql = 'SELECT price FROM loper WHERE id = 79';
```

I DO get the price back.

When running the queries in PHPMyAdmin I get by both queries results back.

**Edit**

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT price FROM loper WHERE id = :id");

$id = 80;
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $data['price'];
```

Above does also not work.

**Edit 2**

When using below MySQLi query I do get the correct price

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pwd","database");
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT price FROM loper WHERE id = 80");
 mysqli_close($con);

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     print_r($record);
}
echo "Total records: " . mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Any errors? Did you check the error log? Try getting the error? `$this->db->error()`

Comment: When I use $this->db->errorInfo() I get when using ID = 80 

    Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) 

when using 79 I get

    Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Prijs

Comment: In itself, both queries are valid and should return a similar result. But something tells me that the query() method is probably a custom method that is set up somewhere in your codebase and it's adding additional conditions (like each result must be of a certain `type`).

Comment: @Oldskool Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to check this ?
The code is very old and written by someone else, so its a puzzle for me :)

Comment: See my edit in my original post

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct table? In the table layout you posted is no column named `prijs`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Yes, I will edit my TS (I always change the fields and values because some DB contains private data :)

Comment: Well, changing vital things like variable and column names inevitably  leads to wrong conclusions. And I can't imagine a variable name being considered "private data". You can change actual data all you want, but changing such things creates confusion and leads on wrong tracks if it is only forgotten in one place.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider : My bad.

all : Second Edit, seems that Oldskool is correct ? But how to find out where because the codebase is a mess (original coder is not available anymore).

Comment: i can't believe this post got 2 upvotes.

Comment: @Sharky : What / Who do you mean ?

Comment: @PostMans you are asking us why a piece of code on your project doesn't work when its rather obvious that in order to help you we will need to have the whole codebase to examine. and thats way out of scope for this site.

Comment: What does the `mysqli` code return? It just says "When using the below query" and no explanation of the outcome.

Comment: @Oldskool : I edited my TS, but mysqli returns the correct price.
So I think your assumption that query is modified is correct.

Comment: @PostMans Yes, this only confirms my suspicion that whatever is in `$this->db` is a customised version of the PDO adapter. You should inspect it more closely.

Comment: @Sharky. Thanks for your explanation.
The problem is the Code base is started +10 years ago (plain PHP), a big mess (code + database) with includes everywhere and that the project is not ours but from someone else. We where asked to add some products and that why I ran at above problem. If it where me I would rewrite the whole thing in a framework, but that aint my decision :(

Comment: @Oldskool : Thanks alot for your help!, will have to investigate the PDO (for now I hacked the MySQLi workaround).

Comment: @PostMans i know, i understand your situation, what i'm saying is, stackoverflow.com is not the right place to help you debug your project. the questions and answers here are "narrowed" to specific problems.